# wordpress xml-rpc using admin user

Tags: android, wordpress, permissions

I am creating an application on Android, that uses wordpress-java API (http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-java) that allows connection to my Wordpress website and adding a post.

My question is - is it secured to use admin user and password from my application? Is it recommended?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you'd ask for credentials within the Android app. Some other way is to create a user in WP with read-only rights, of which you can store the credentials in your Android app safely. In latter case, people using the app can read from your blog, but if they want to post something, they'd have to 'log in' (~= store their own credentials so they could elevate their rights on the blog).